# Does creating partitions using pg_partman locks the table

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

We are exploring and comparing pg_partman and timescale for auto creation and maintenance of partitions. The post here says pg_partman locks the table and may block writes on table. https://www.timescale.com/learn/pg_partman-vs-hypertables-for-postgres-partitioning

Is this still true? And for how long does pg_partman locks the table while creating new partitions?

Comment: FWIW, Partitioning isn't the correct tool to make `SELECT` queries faster, if that's your goal - despite all the misinformation out there.